# Проблема UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode. Python 3

Tags: python, unicode, decode

При отправке сообщения на почту выдает ошибку. Пробовал использовать `.encode.decode`, но совсем запутался.

```
def mailinfo(text): # отправить по почте
    smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    smtpObj.starttls()
    smtpObj.login('otkogo@mail.ru', 'pass')
    print(text) #нормально принтит любой текст в консоли
    smtpObj.sendmail("otkogo@mail.ru", "komu@gmail.com", text)#выдает ошибку если в text есть русские символы
    smtpObj.quit()
```

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position ... : ordinal not in range(128)
```

Понимаю что проблема в кодировке, перечитал интернет, не могу понять как решить.

Comment: А на какой строке возникает ошибка?  Какие версии Питона и библиотеки `smtplib`?

Comment: Ошибка начинается в строке текста, и далее везде где текст используется. Python 3.7 smtlib встроенная в питон библиотека

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте `.encode('utf-8')` должно помочь

Comment: если сделать так, то оно отправляется, но на почту приходит типа этого : b'\xd0\xbe\xd1\x82\xd0\xb7\xd1\x8b\xd0\xb2', а нужно что бы приходил читаемый текст)

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете явно указать кодировку в письме, для этого можно использовать модуль `email.mime.text` следующим образом:

```py
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

...

def mailinfo(text): # отправить по почте
    message = MIMEText(text, "plain", "utf-8") # Преобразуем text в message
    message['Subject'] = 'Тема'
    message['From'] = 'otkogo@mail.ru'
    message['To'] = 'komu@gmail.com'

    smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    smtpObj.starttls()
    smtpObj.login('otkogo@mail.ru', 'pass')
    server.send_message(message)
    smtpObj.quit()
```